# Hadoop - Input directory issue

Tags: hadoop, input, mapreduce

The main problem is that the program launches an 
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/davide/wordcount/input already exists`

The command I run to launch the job is the following:
`hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.wordcount.WordCount /user/davide/wordcount/input /user/davide/wordcount/output` which seems correct (the output directory does not exist, as hadoop pretends).

In the java file the paths seem to be correctly set:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

I tried several solutions, but couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your argument numbering: `args[0]` is actually `org.wordcount.WordCount`, and so you need to use `args[1]` for input and `args[2]` for output. If you notice, the error says `Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/davide/wordcount/input already exists` - it's trying to use the `input` folder as output.

To fix this:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
```